# Why are there two Right Shift operators and only a single Left Shift operator in Java?

Tags: java, operators

I am new to java, and came to know that there are two Right Shift operators in java `>>` and `>>>`, but only one  left shift operator `<<`. Why is it so?

Comment: Based on what you know about the right-shift operators, do you have any ideas?

Comment: That is explained in the [tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) too.

Comment: @PeterMmm sorry, page not found

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because logical and arithmetic left-shift operations are identical ([from wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Shifts_in_Java)).

- [Arithmetic shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Arithmetic_shift)

[image: Right]
[image: Left]

- [Logical shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Logical_shift)

[image: Right]
[image: Left]

Notice what happens to sign bit (left-most bit) in both **left** shifts.

Answer (score 3):

The right shift operators are one with (`>>`) and one without (`>>>`) sign-extension. The left shift operation does not have a sign extension component.

For instance, the following expressions are both true:

```
(0x80000000 >>  1) == 0xC0000000
(0x80000000 >>> 1) == 0x40000000
```

Comment: why.? i am new here, forgive me if i am asking silly question

Comment: @sum2000 Where's the sign bit?

Comment: @DaveNewton are you here to answer or ask ?

Comment: @DaveNewton Stop bullying people around ;) Maybe he's just reading some "Java for newbies" manual which says "Java has >>, >>> but no <<", and he got curious why is that.

Comment: @sum2000 I'm here to encourage you to think for yourself when there are so many resources with which to do so. Are you here to be spoon-fed or to learn how to learn?

Comment: @DaveNewton if you think bullying people and writing funny comments would earn you more repu, then go on!!!

Comment: @Max Asking a leading question is bullying?

Comment: @sum2000 Comments are not considered when calculating reputation. Since when is asking a perfectly reasonable question "bullying"?

Comment: @DaveNewton You've obviously noticed that the guy does not know what he's talking about. Still you are asking him a question that you know he can't answer. I call that bullying.

Comment: @Max And yet I am the one that has faith he can use the information provided to come up with some ideas, while you believe he's incapable of figuring it out through reason... ironic that the one who believes he's smart is the one accused of bullying.

Comment: If **I** had no idea what a sign bit is, I would just google for it. Which would certainly lead me to 2complement representation. And with that newly found information I could then answer not only dave's question but would even understand the difference in the operators. @Dave Don't you worry, sum2000 also claimed I was absolutely wrong when I answered one of his questions (including a counter example of why it is so) - I think he just likes to argue :)