# How do the left shifting operator preserve sign?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit, bit-shift

I [looked in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8562099/why-there-are-two-right-shift-operators-and-single-left-shift-operator-in-java) to understand why there is no arithmetic left shift operator in most languages including Java . But then how do we deal with negative integers because left shifting would throw it away . Take for example -2^5 where the result should be negative .

Comment: If you're expecting negatives, check, take it out, bit shift, put it back

Comment: It is indeed possible for a left shift to throw away the sign. That happens in exactly those cases where the result would not have fit anyway - so there is nothing you can do about it, but it almost never matters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, the sign bit will never be thrown out by left shift unless you commit an overflow. Reason? In two's complement encoding the negative number has all ones on te left side, where a positive number would have all zeros. It's like the sign bit is replicated to the right. BTW this is exactly why the term "sign extension" makes sense, which is how the default right-shift works in Java.

```
  int i = -1;
  System.out.format("%3d = %s\n", i, Integer.toBinaryString(i));
  i <<= 5;
  System.out.format("%3d = %s\n", i, Integer.toBinaryString(i));
```

prints

```
 -1 = 11111111111111111111111111111111
-32 = 11111111111111111111111111100000
```

Comment: can you give an example using bit positions to explain your second paragraph ?

Comment: -1 is not represented by 1000001, but by 1111111 (sign extension convention). Thus, left-shifting doesn't remove the negative sign bit, unless you shift too much.

Answer (score 0):

My best answer for that, would have to be to just change the sign before and after the operation. It might appear too obvious but the thing is that the bits get changed in a particular way when the sign changes

Comment: It all depends on how the negative binary is being represented though. Marko Topolnik's answer work on my test